# lambdas require capturing 'this' to call static member function?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

For the following code:

```
struct B
{
    void g()
    {
        []() { B::f(); }();
    }

    static void f();
};
```

g++ 4.6 gives the error:

> test.cpp: In lambda function:
>    test.cpp:44:21: error: 'this' was not captured for this lambda function

(Interestingly, g++ 4.5 compiles the code fine).

Is this a bug in g++ 4.6, or is it really necessary to capture the 'this' parameter to be able to call a static member function? I don't see why it should be, I even qualified the call with `B::`.

Comment: That would be a bug.

Comment: Still a bug in GCC 4.7.2. Adding `this` as a capture still works.

Comment: g++ 5.4 same problem

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I agree, it should compile just fine. For the fix (if you didn't know already), add the reference capture (`[&]`) and it will compile fine on GCC 4.6:

```cpp
struct B
{
    void g()
    {
        [&]() { B::f(); }();
    }

    static void f() { std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; };
};
```

Comment: Could they have made lambda's more ugly?  Don't answer that.  At least we've got them.

Comment: @wheaties I am disappointed they couldn't work in `<>` somehow. Just to go for the full set of brackets...

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: There is an example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293599.aspx: auto g = [](int x) -> function<int (int)> 
      { return [=](int y) { return x + y; }; };