# What are lookup rules when calling function from lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11

The following example demonstrates the problem I encountered in VC++ 2010:

```cpp
class Foo
{
    template<class T>
    static T foo(T t) { return t; }

public:
    void test()
    {
        auto lambda = []() { return foo(1); }; // call to Foo::foo<int>
        lambda();
    }
};
```

VC++ produces: **error C3861: `'foo'`: identifier not found**

If I qualify the call to foo: `Foo::foo(1);` then this example compiles with a warning:
**warning C4573: the usage of `'Foo::foo'` requires the compiler to capture `'this'` but the current default capture mode does not allow it**

What does the standard say about this case? Should unqualified name be found? Does the qualified name require capturing `this`?

Comment: Hm, that's weird. It's static, so it shouldn't require `this`. I suspect it's compiler bug and that not finding it is side-effect of compiler thinking it needs `this` to use it.

Comment: This happens with g++ as well so it doesn't seem like a bug. If you change it to [&]() instead of []() then this compiles fine but that's because it takes the this by reference.

Comment: Having said that [another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940259/c0x-lambdas-require-capturing-this-to-call-static-member-function) says it is a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft has been seeing this problem reported in a number of cases.  See:

[Scope Resolution with lambdas interferes with namespace and type resolution](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/526672/lambda-scope-resolution-fails-with-locally-defined-scopes)

[Template resolution in lambdas](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/544033/visual-c-failure-to-compile-call-to-member-function-with-explicit-template-argument-list-from-lambda)

As you've found out, explicit resolution allows it to find the name.  There is an additional warning about this which is also a compiler error (name resolution doesn't require access to this, though I can see how a compiler implementation might require it) - it's a separate bug though.  Microsoft has confirmed this to be a bug and have apparently prepared a fix for the next release.

Answer (score 2):

The following compiles fine. It seems to me that this must just be a VS bug with templates.

```
struct Foo {
    static void foo() {}
    void bar() {
        auto f = []() { foo(); };
        f();
    }
};
```

Comment: What compiler did you try? It seems the result varies depending on compiler, so it's important to know the standard conforming behavior.

Comment: @Gene : VC++ 2010 implemented lambdas pre-[N2927](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2927.pdf), so it is **not** conformant to the FDIS' wording.