# use c++11 lambda in non-static member function and call static member function of same class

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [lambdas require capturing 'this' to call static member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940259/c11-lambdas-require-capturing-this-to-call-static-member-function)

I want to use c++11 lambda in a non-static member function and call a static member function of same class:

```
class A {
    static void a() {}
public:
    void x() {
        [] () { A::a(); }();
    }
};
```

But gcc4.6 and gcc4.7 both got an error:
error: 'this' was not captured for this lambda function

Why does lambda need 'this' since 'a' is a static member function.

And if 'x' is static or 'a' is static member function of other class, 'this' is not necessary, why?

Comment: Why do you require lambda in this case? why don't you simple call `A::a()`?

Comment: VS2010 SP1 compiles and runs without any error.

Comment: The other question doesn't have the appropriate bug id though. Should it be edited in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A {
    static void a() {}
public:
    void x() {
        [] () { A::a(); }();
    }
};

int main() { A a; a.x(); }
```

This compiles fine with clang 3.2. Also, there is no reason why this shouldn't be compile. This is a [bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51494) in GCC as per the notes. This ought to be fixed in 4.7.1. Note that gcc started early but has lagged behind clang in supporting some of the C++11 features.

Edit: There is a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940259/c11-lambdas-require-capturing-this-to-call-static-member-function) which you may want to check out.

Comment: Seems it is a gcc's bug and gcc4.7.1 is still wrong. Wish 4.7.2 can fix it.

Comment: @sealiay: I think you should post your findings on GCC's bug notes! (Don't forget to mention the platform you're on and other required details.)