# thread - How to access a member variable inside a lambda function?

Tags: c++, multithreading

My case is specific to threads:

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    
    std::vector<std::thread> threadVector;  
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    
    std::mutex              objMutex;
    std::condition_variable objCondVar;
    
    int counter;
    
    void func( int arg )
    {
        std::unique_lock< std::mutex > objUniqueLock( objMutex );
        objCondVar.wait( objUniqueLock, [arg]{ return (arg == counter); } );
                
        std::cout << "\nnumber: " << numbers[counter];  
        
        counter++;
    }
    
    A() 
    {
        counter = 0;
        
        numbers.push_back(10);
        numbers.push_back(20);
        numbers.push_back(30);
                                
        threadVector.push_back( std::thread( &A::func, this, 1 ));
        threadVector.push_back( std::thread( &A::func, this, 2 ));  
        threadVector.push_back( std::thread( &A::func, this, 3 ));  
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
}
```

I saw this thread [lambdas require capturing 'this' to call static member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940259/lambdas-require-capturing-this-to-call-static-member-function)

But I think this case is specific to thread function whereas that is a general function case.

What is the way to access the class member `counter` in the lambda function?

```
error: ‘this’ was not captured for this lambda function
```

Comment: By capturing `[this, arg]` ?

Comment: Okay, you fixed *one* error. But how is this question different to the one you deleted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63603755/how-to-use-function-arguments-and-class-members-in-a-thread-in-c11

Comment: @storyteller I realise that I really did not understand the meaning of the error and how that solved in the other deleted question.

Comment: The solution of a good SO netizen to that is to edit your post, to emphasize that. You didn't. You haven't even added that detail to this repost. It looks virtually identical to the deleted question.

Comment: @storyteller what is the way to do that? That question has been closed as a duplicate. If I edit it , it will require votes of 5 people for reopening. That will take ages. Kindly correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: It will take 3 people to re-open. Or one gold-badge holder. Either way, that is absolutely no excuse to repost. Flooding near identical questions to circumvent closure is not acting in good faith.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used `counter` without capturing it and note that you are capturing `arg` by value. By the following, you are capturing `counter` and `arg` by `ref`

```
void func( int arg )
{
    std::unique_lock< std::mutex > objUniqueLock( objMutex );
    objCondVar.wait( objUniqueLock, [&]{ return (arg == counter); } );

    std::cout << "\nnumber: " << numbers[counter];

    counter++;
}
```

If u want to capture them by `value` use `=` instead of `&` but I think this is unwanted.

Comment: Why assume he wants to capture by ref? no side effect inside.

Comment: Please tell a good resource to learn about lambda functions in c++.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl start with cppreference [Lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing specific to thread functionality about this -- the language requires that you capture `this` in the Lambda's capture list in order to use any member state of the surrounding class.

The code should be

```cpp
        objCondVar.wait( objUniqueLock, [this, arg]{ return (arg == counter); } );
```